# Root site collection token in appending html

Tags: 2010, development, site-collection, html, image

I have following code

```
builder.AppendFormat("<img style='border:0; left:-0px !important;position:absolute;' id='AddQuickTagImg_{0}' alt=\"{1}\" src='<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Images/MyImage_32.png %>'/></span>", this.ClientID, likeTooltip);
```

The problem i have is following thing:

```
 <% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/Style Library/Images/MyImage_32.png %>
```

Specifying this in this way, doesn't return me the correct image :( 
How can i solve this?

~sitecollection means root site collection? or it is just closest site collection? Imagine nested site collections, which site collection it will be outer of inner?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should get the URL using SPContext.Current.Site.Url:

```
var siteCollUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;
builder.AppendFormat("<img style='border:0; left:-0px !important;position:absolute;' id='AddQuickTagImg_{0}' alt=\"{1}\" src='{2}'/></span>", this.ClientID, likeTooltip, siteCollUrl);
```